Can't login - Session Already Running
Out of nowhere, I can't login today. I get a message saying that I cannot login because there is a session already running. It gives me the option to "Force Stop" but pressing that button does nothing.
I am running 24.04 on a Dell laptop (Gnome). This is not a new setup. I migrated to 24.04 from 23.10 the day it came out. It has been running well so far, until this. See this

I've searched everywhere but all I get are references to VNC sessions being active.
Thanks for your help!

Login with what to what? What are the softwares running on each end? Please edit the question and add this critical info.

sudo pkill -KILL -u <username> works for me too, but every time I logged in I had to repeat the command.
I was only able to resolve it when I removed a program that was starting a remote session, in my case chrome-remote-desktop

Thanks. It solved my issue too

Sorry but where did you enter this command, if you can't log in?

If U use Ctrl+Alt+F2, linux switch between GUI and CLI. Then you can log in and use your machine

Never mind... I did sudo pkill -KILL -u <username> and that closed all the processes related to the user. I was able to login after that.

Thanks A Cavazos. I faced some issue and solved with your solution. However. I need to run your command every login. Did you fix on your side?

No, it hasn’t happened again. I did remove Chrome Remote Desktop. That is probably the reason. Have you tried removing it on your side?

@ACavazos not op but I had the same problem and it was indeed caused by Chrome Remote Desktop. Thanks for the tip!

Had the same issue. srgusty's solution worked fine to me. However following power-on showed the same behavior again. I disabled chrome-remote-desktop service as advised in https://superuser.com/questions/1663763/how-do-i-stop-chrome-remote-desktop-on-unix-or-prevent-it-running-on-startup and that fixed up so far.
